# C pointers arithmetic for arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm reading the section on array arithmetic in K&R and came across something curious. I posted the whole paragraph for context, but I'm mainly focused on the bold part:

> If `p` and `q` point to members of the same array, then relations like `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>=`, etc. work properly. For example, `p < q` is true if `p` points to an earlier member of the array than `q` does. Any pointer can be meaningfully compared for equality or inequality with zero. But the behavior is undefined for arithmetic or comparisons with pointers that do not point to members of the same array. (There is one exception: the address of the first element past the end of an array can be used in pointer arithmetic.)

I got some answers here ([C pointer arithmetic for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172984/c-pointer-arithmetic-for-arrays/75281634#75281634)) but I have doubts described below:

I have a doubt in this since the following code seems to work with dereferencing and comparisons without throwing any exception or errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int *p = &a[7];
    int *q = &b[3];
    printf("%d\n", p);
    printf("%d\n", q);
    printf("%d\n", q > p); // relational from different arrays
    printf("%d", *p);      // dereferencing also seems to work
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

The code should throw an error.

Comment: "`But the behavior is undefined for arithmetic or comparisons with pointers that do not point to members of the same array.`" Undefined means undefined. What appears to work using one compiler may not work using another... A sample size of one is not a good basis to make an assessment.

Comment: "The code should throw an error" That's the wrong assumption. It is mostly the programmer's job to check for undefined behavior, not the compiler nor the OS. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: This code is not guaranteed to work. It might, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: "The code should throw an error." --> No. "should throw an error" means that there exist a specification that some code should error.  Yet the behavior is not defined. There is no  _should_ do anything with UB.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has undefined behavior in multiple places, but the C language does not define what happens in case of undefined behavior: anything can happen. There is no exception or error to be thrown, the program may crash, produce unexpected results or seem to work and produce expected results... anything goes, nothing can be expected.

There is undefined behaviour in these places:

- `int *p = &a[7];` you compute the address of a non existing element of the `a` array beyond the end of the array and not the element just after the end.
- `printf("%d\n", p);` you pass a pointer to `int` where `printf` expects an `int`. You should write `printf("%p\n", (void *)p);`
- `printf("%d\n", q);` same as above
- `printf("%d\n", q > p);` using the value of `p` which was not initialized to a valid expression
- `printf("%d", *p);` dereferencing invalid pointer `p`.

Note that the C Standard is more precise than the K&R book about the comparison of pointers for equality:

> **6.5.8 Relational operators**
>
> 5 For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the  rst element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.
>
> 6 When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P. In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.

> **6.5.9 Equality operators**
>
> 6 ... If one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant, the null pointer constant is converted to the type of the pointer. If one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, the former is converted to the type of the latter.
>
> 7 Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

Here is a modified version with defined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int *p = &a[3];
    int *q = &a[5];
    int *r = &b[0];

    // printing pointer values
    printf("p:      %p\n", (void *)p);
    printf("q:      %p\n", (void *)q);
    printf("r:      %p\n", (void *)r);

    // p, q and r can be compared to 0
    printf("p == 0: %d\n", p == 0);  // outputs 0
    printf("q != 0: %d\n", q != 0);  // outputs 1
    printf("!r:     %d\n", !r);      // outputs 0

    // p and q can be compared for equality and order
    printf("p < q:  %d\n", p < q);  // outputs 1
    printf("p != q: %d\n", p != q); // outputs 1

    // p and r can only be compared for equality
    printf("p != r: %d\n", p != r); // outputs 1

    // q and r can only be compared for equality but the result is unspecified:
    //   it is compiler dependent depends on the memory layout
    printf("q != r: %d\n", q != r); // may output 1 or 0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Why is it considered as an undefined behavior since in the end we are comparing the different memory addresses whether the pointer belongs to the same array or not?                             //   it is compiler dependent depends on the memory layout
    printf("q != r: %d\n", q != r); // may output 1 or 0                                                                               2) Why is it compiler dependent here?Please clarify about the memory layout.                            3) What is the basis of the above rules? Can you please share the link of the book c standard. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are working with **undefined behavior**.
This means you can't rely on it - it may work well one day, may not work at all on another.
But no matter what - you can't trust it.

And that's why undefined behavior is so dangerous. Sometimes it may work fine  until failing horribly one day with no prior warning.

Comment: I think the UB stems from _compilers_ not being _required_ to do one thing, or the other.  So it's not that it will "work one day, but not on another," but that one _compiler_ will do certain things, while _a different compiler_ will have generated other code, yielding different results.  Because the compilers are not required by the standard to do one thing or the other.

Comment: @mmixLinus Although much observed UB may be compiler dependent, UB may still "work one day, but not on another," for a given compilation.

Comment: This is a mischaracterization of what the C standard calls undefined behavior. For example, calling an operating system routine is undefined behavior as the C standard defines the term, but we expect that the behavior is defined by the operating system documentation, that you can rely on it, and that it will not work one day and fail the next. The C standard’s definition of undefined behavior is neutral—it is neither good nor bad and neither inherently “so dangerous” nor necessarily beneficial; it is simply something the standard does not specify.